# Confirm SonarQube result is for master Branch

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Because I don't know if Sonar is doing something strange, I just wanted to confirm that it is indeed scanning the master branch and not the feature branch.

[image]

People on my team are saying SonarCube ran the test against the feature branch. As near as I can figure, it ran the test on the master branch. We are using Sonar 7.9.1 and my intent is to run against the feature branch.

Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
            stage('Send sonarqube reports') {
                sh """
                    sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_CIRRUS} -Dsonar.java.libraries=/home/bcjenkins/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.8/lombok-1.18.8.jar
                """
                JSON_STRING_SONAR_METRICS = sh (
                    script: "curl -X GET -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' -H \'Accept: application/octet-stream\' \'${SONAR_CIRRUS}/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator\'",
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
                println "The JSON_STRING_SONAR_METRICS=${JSON_STRING_SONAR_METRICS}";
                def sonarQube_Results = readJSON text: "${JSON_STRING_SONAR_METRICS}";
                def CodeCoverageEntryThreshold = sonarQube_Results.projectStatus.status;

                if(CodeCoverageEntryThreshold == "ERROR"){
                    error("[cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator] Code qualitygates did not PASSED. Please check the results in our Sonarqube server.\n" +
                    "\tTo view the sonarqube results-> ${SONAR_CIRRUS}/dashboard?id=cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator\n")
                }
            
                else if(CodeCoverageEntryThreshold == "FAILED"){
                    error("[cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator] Code qualitygates did not PASSED. Please check the results in our Sonarqube server.\n" +
                    "\tTo view the sonarqube results-> ${SONAR_CIRRUS}/dashboard?id=cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator\n")
                }

                else {
                    CodeCoverage_resultMsg = "[cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator] Code qualitygates PASSED. Please check the results in our Sonarqube server.\n" +
                    "\tTo view the sonarqube results-> ${SONAR_CIRRUS}/dashboard?id=cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator\n";
                    slackSend channel: "${SONAR_SLACK_CHANNEL}", color: 'good', failOnError: false, message: "${CodeCoverage_resultMsg}", teamDomain: 'ibm-ic2e-sprint', tokenCredentialId: SLACK_DOMAIN_CREDENTIALS
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/

> **Master / Main Branch**
>
> This is the default branch and typically corresponds to what's being
> developed for your next release. This branch is usually known within a
> development team as "master" or "head" and is analyzed when no
> specific branch parameters are provided. SonarQube labels this branch
> as Main Branch, and, ***with Community Edition, this is the only branch***
> ***you can analyze***.

If we use the **SonarQube** *Community Edition*, we are able to analyze the `main` or `mater` branch only.

If we need to analyze another branches, we should use at least the **SonarQube** *Developer Edition* as the following mentioned: -

> **Branch Analysis**
>
> Branch analysis is available starting in ***Developer Edition***.

#### Edit 1:

The **SonarQube** provide the *SonarLint* (https://www.sonarlint.org/) as an IDE extension, including with **Eclipse**, **IntelliJ IDEA** and so on.

We are able to configure our IDE to connect to the in-house **SonarQube** server and use this plugin to perform a local analyzing at the developer machine before merging them to the master or main branch.

#### Edit 2:

The example for configuring the **SonarLint** with **Eclipse** is at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-eclipse/wiki/Connected-Mode

Comment: Thanks @Charlee. So if we were only using the Community Edition, it's not possible to evaluate our code using it before merging into the master branch? This seems like a huge shortcoming, I wish I knew a way around it.

Comment: Sonar scanner or sonar-maven? Community Edition runs against the "checked out branch" or the default branch. CE really does not know about branches, just code. Confusing results if you keep checking out different branches. You could create a branch to merge features into and always scan that, back out change if it fails. Use features, merge to RC or analysis branch, analyze that. Just pick what you want the [default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/changing-the-default-branch) to be. SonarLint can help too.